# MongoDB - security problems

Tags: mongodb, security

I have MongoDB v3.4.6 on my VPS.  From time to time someone deletes all the data from collections and creates a new collection with a message where he demands that I give him a ransom.
So far it's all nice, but it's a little tired of me.
I want to understand where the vulnerability of my database is.
As far as I know in this version of `MongoDB` only local access is allowed. No one except me has access to the server...
On mongo start I have following warnings

> ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
>   ** Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.

But I really don't understand why should I protect the DB with password if only local connection is allowed.

Comment: Can you confirm it listens only on local interface? `lsof -i | grep 27017 | grep LISTEN` in the console of the VPS that hosts the db

Comment: @AlexBlex `mongod    1149        root    6u  IPv4     53168      0t0  TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)`

Comment: Does it mean that mongo listens to all IPs? In mongod.conf I have `net:   port: 27017   bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: yep, it listens on public IP and is wide open to anyone from the Internet. It probably doesn't use this config. Check `ps aux | grep mongod`.

Comment: ah, and btw running it as 'root' is not a good idea either.

Comment: Note that MongoDB version 3.6 and newer by default will bind only to localhost (and thus won't accept any external connection). Version 3.4.6 still binds to all IPs by default, so it will be open to the world if you don't restrict it. I would also check your VPS setting and confirm that you don't open your VPS to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @AlexBlex and @ Kevin Adistambha Thank you very much. I removed the old version of mongo and installed the 4.0.2 version. No I see that by default in listens only to localhost.